# Wrap the 2 firsts words of title with a <Span>

Tags: wp-title

I would like to enclose the 2 first word of title inside a  to get the following result:

TOP 5 of best photos

I tried using the code below, but it returns only the first word. How can i do to select 2 words?

Thank you

```
    function add_label_to_post_title( $title = '' ) {
       if(trim($title) != "")
       {
      $ARR_title = explode(" ", $title);

      if(sizeof($ARR_title) > 1 )
          {
             $first_word = "<span>".$ARR_title['0']."</span> ";
             unset($ARR_title['0']);
             return $first_word. implode(" ", $ARR_title);
          }
          else
          {
              return "{$title}";
          }
       }
       return $title;
    } add_filter( 'the_title', 'add_label_to_post_title' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that like this:

```
function add_label_to_post_title( $title = '' ) {
    global $post;

    if( 'post' == $post->post_type && trim( $title ) != "" ){
        $title_words = explode( " ", $title );
        $word_count = count( $title_words );

        //Sets how many words should be wrapped
        $words_to_wrap = 2;
        $last_word_index = $word_count > $words_to_wrap ? $words_to_wrap - 1 : $word_count - 1;

        $title_words[0] = '<span>' . $title_words[0];
        $title_words[ $last_word_index ] = $title_words[ $last_word_index ] . '</span>';

        $title = implode( ' ', $title_words );
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'add_label_to_post_title' );
```

You can change the value of `$words_to_wrap` to choose how many words should be wrapped in the span element.
If a title has less words than `$words_to_wrap` value it would wrap only the available ones.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for this. It works well. But is there a way to make it apply only to post title? Not on page... Or if it's not possible to select post can i add somewhere before a condition that the text has a minimum 4 words.

I tried to add this before: if( sizeof($title) > 3 ) but it's not working.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the code to limit the function to posts only.

Comment: Super! Apreciated your help!

Comment: Hello. I have a new question. I noticed it was also adding the wrap in admin and also in title from gamify rank. From admin, I found the way to hide, but ti avoid it wrap ranks, how can I add information that the filter apply only when there are more than 2 words? Thank you for your help

Comment: Hi, What is gamify rank? Are the titles you want to add the span inside the loop only? If so just add if( ! in_the_loop() ){ return $title; } at the top of the function.

Comment: Hello, thank you. I will try this. Gamify is an extension that helps to give point to the community website. In my case, I use it to encourage people to post content or visit my website. They have points for every content they post or when they share or visit the website. Every time they reach a special amount, their rank is upgrading and at this point, there is a popup coming inside the website telling them the newrank.